# expression after group by has same result

Tags: sqlite

Why query:

```
SELECT id, MAX(probe_time) AS Expr1
FROM app_states
GROUP BY logon_id
```

and

```
SELECT id, MIN(probe_time) AS Expr1
FROM app_states
GROUP BY logon_id
```

has same `id` result.

I wish to select row with MAX or MIN time for every user.

Comment: why are you selecting `id` but grouping by `logon_id`?

Comment: this is subquery, and I want to use id for later joins. I want to select with linq query like above and use id for joins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid you'll have to use sub queries here.

```
SELECT id, probe_time
FROM app_states
WHERE probe_time = (SELECT MAX(probe_time) from app_states GROUP BY logon_id)
```

**BTW**, SQLite does interesting optimization on MIN/MAX:

> Queries of the following forms will be optimized to run in logarithmic time assuming appropriate indices exist:
>
> ```
>  SELECT MIN(x) FROM table;
>  SELECT MAX(x) FROM table;
> ```
>
> In order for these optimizations to occur, they must appear in exactly the form shown above - changing only the name of the table and column. It is not permissible to add a WHERE clause or do any arithmetic on the result. The result set must contain a single column. The column in the MIN or MAX function must be an indexed column.

— http://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html#minmax